# In Visual 2010 it is not showing conflict when I merge a renamed file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, merge

So I have a file (let's call this x.txt in the following path $initial files/Development) and I branch it here ($initial files/Test). I then check in all the changes. Now I edit the x.txt file in $initial files/Development, rename it to xyz.txt check that in. And now I merge it to $initial files/Test but it does not say that there is a conflict in the name. Is this not how this is supposed to work?

I know I can delete the file from test then branch it again from development branch but I know for sure that this used to work but all of a sudden it is not working now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Did you actually create a conflict? The same file being modified in the source and destination isn't necessarily a conflict.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a conflict if you have a file as xyz then rename it to abc and merge it (this is assuming xyz was branched previously).

Comment: No, that is not a conflict.  TFS is smart enough to know you are renaming it.

Comment: So why would it not automatically rename it in the target branch as well. I did a merge on a .sql file yesterday to the test branch from dev (which was renamed) and I did get a conflict for which I chose the option to take from the source branch. I then went to the test branch where the file was named something like this (before the check in ofcourse) Originalname[NewName].sql and after I checked it in it became NewName.sql

Comment: Sorry it was NewName.sql[Originalname.sql] and not like i mentioned in my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rename will not cause a conflict.

However, you will get a conflict when you merge if the file in target branch ($initial files/Test/x.txt) in local workspace is not the latest version. So, to avoid the conflict, please first get latest version on for files on target branch and then do merge.